# need help with hard drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hard-drive, uninstall

So I have installed Ubuntu on my 1 TB EXTERNAL hard drive. I also have windows on another drive (its not external). I can't boot from my external one which has Ubuntu on it. I have to go to the other one to boot from it so if I tried installing another distro like arch on my external drive would it get rid of the part that launches Ubuntu that is currently on the windows drive? or would it stay there?

i haven't tired anything yet because i don't want to mess up my computer

Comment: I need more info, which windows is installed, and was it preinstalled, for first.

Comment: windows 7 yes preinstalled

Comment: Do you can tell me if you have a ESP partion on your internal drive?

Comment: what is an ESP partition?

Comment: If it is 64 bit it should have one, if it is 32 then not.

Comment: The ESP is the partion where the bootloader and kernel are stored on UEFI systems, Windows normaly hides it from the user. It should be a 300 MiB FAT32 partion as first partion on your internal drive.

Comment: its 64 bit. yow do i check if there is one?

Answer (score 0):

First off it is NEVER recommended to run any operating system on an ANY external drive. That being said I have had a similar problem. If your external drive is a HDD meaning it has a spinning disk then the problem is that your bios wants to boot something faster then you external drive can spin up. To fix this go into BIOS and most likely a boot tab and look for something that says Harddisk Delay and set it to something higher. This will delay the boot process and allow time for your external drive to spin up allowing bios to detect it.

Comment: k im trying it now

Comment: @PizzaCat Let me know how it works out.

Comment: is this the boot delay you were talking about i uploaded it to imgur

Comment: http://imgur.com/NIom7go

Comment: @PizzaCat Yes it is. Setting that to a higher value will allow time for your external drive to spin up and to be detected. Please keep in mind that most external drives are super slow, and not ideal for running an operating system. My advice would be to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows on your internal drive. But yes the POST delay will work.

Comment: didnt work i just booted into ubuntu i dont think that disk has a boot partition actually

Comment: nope just doesnt have one